# Notification panel vs banners

Tags: notification, alerts

When do you normally add notifications to a slide-out panel vs using a banner for it?

By slide-out panel, this is similar to what I mean:
[image]

By banner, this is similar to what I mean (but with a dismiss (x) option):
[image]

**In our app**, we have the option to **do both**.

But I would like to add a notification that I'd really like to get a user's attention on, but at the same time it's also not crucial to their process.

Would it be more appropriate to add it to the slide-out panel? Or would it be better as a (dismissible) banner?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of the content, the dismissable toast banner would be more appropriate because the user would have to click and open the slide-out panel. These panels are not typically used for validation notification messages. If the user does not need to refer to the content again, use a toast banner instead.

A toast banner that is both dismissable and disappears after a short time is a better fit for your purpose: the initial appearance catches the user's attention but it is also unobtrusive and goes away after awhile.

Comment: By "toast banner", do you mean ones that appear at the very top of the page? Or do you mean similar to snackbars that show up at the bottom left?

Comment: The ones that appear at the top of the screen or page.